# Why removing node_modules is still required to fix some npm problems?

Tags: node.js, npm

npm 1.0 was released in May 2011, yet with it's latest release as of today, I still often run into a lot of problematic situations that can only be solved by [removing node_modules](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=remove%20node_modules). Of course sometimes it is enough to reinstall some package, or rebuild another, but as of 2018, the consensus seem to be that the ultimate solution is to remove node_modules and run `npm install` again. I wonder - why is it the case? I'd imagine that most difficult bugs are already solved since the 1.0 release, does it have something to do with the design? I found that [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/) is free from this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Much like "turning it off and on again", it's a very simple action that in almost all cases will sort out what's wrong with no damage.

Then once it's sorted, there's not much incentive for the user to pursue it, and all evidence of what the problem was will be gone.

The bug remains of low importance (because there's an easy workaround) and high difficulty (no evidence, may be hard to reproduce), so doesn't get fixed.